# Rank repository apps by popularity/downloads/votes

Tags: software-center, gnome-software

**Is there a place/tool that rank apps based on given statistics?** For example, say I want to see which music player is more popular (amarok, clementine, gmusicbrowser...)

Gnome Software does not have that information. I know there are some statistics in the [Debian Popularity Contest](http://popcon.debian.org/), but you can only search *one app at the time*. Additionally, *you need to know the app* you are looking for (which does not allow you to discover those that you do not know), and, you can search only using *the name of the package*, which might not coincide with the app name.

Any idea? Maybe using some type of script that gets a list of related packages (from where?) and look up for them in the aforementioned website? Perhaps using a web scrapper tool? This could be a nice feature to have in Gnome Software and in [Ubuntu apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/), and surely not too difficult to implement.

Comment: "This could be a nice feature to have in Gnome Software and in Ubuntu apps, and surely not too difficult to implement." File a feature request and submit a patch, then.

Comment: Maybe, but it does sound like you're disparaging the people who do work on these programs. If it is so easy, why aren't you contributing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know there are some statistics in the Debian Popularity Contest, but you can only search one app at the time. Additionally, you need to know the app you are looking for (which does not allow you to discover those that you do not know), and, you can search only using the name of the package, which might not coincide with the app name.

If you look in `/usr/share/app-install/desktop`, you'll see a list of `.desktop` files for applications available in the Software Center.

Each of these `.desktop` files has a line with a Popcon score. For example, the Audacious music player has this:
`X-AppInstall-Popcon=1395`

It is possible to scan all the .desktop files, or just a subset, for their Popcon scores. The code in the following example looks at a subset of .desktop files that contain any of the following strings: audio, media, music, or video.

```
cd /usr/share/app-install/desktop
grep -iE "(audio|media|music|video)" *.desktop | awk -F: '{ print $1":"$2 }' | sort -u | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 grep -A5 Popcon
```

- `grep` is used to get a list of such .desktop files.
- `awk` extracts just the actual filenames and duplicates are removed using `sort -u`
- `tr` makes the output from `sort` suitable to `xargs`
- `xargs` takes the filenames, now separated by null bytes, and appends each filename as an argument to `grep`.
- `grep` lists out the .desktop files with their Popcon scores on the first line and, on a subsequent line, you mostly will see the applications common name. There's some ambiguity about which exact line the common name will appear on, because not all .desktop files have exactly the same structure!

Here's are some "successful" samples:

Amarok

```
amarok:kde4__amarok.desktop:X-AppInstall-Popcon=2313
amarok:kde4__amarok.desktop-X-AppInstall-Section=universe
amarok:kde4__amarok.desktop-
amarok:kde4__amarok.desktop-Type=Application
amarok:kde4__amarok.desktop-Version=1.0
amarok:kde4__amarok.desktop-Name=Amarok
```

Clementine

```
clementine:clementine.desktop:X-AppInstall-Popcon=919
clementine:clementine.desktop-X-AppInstall-Section=universe
clementine:clementine.desktop-
clementine:clementine.desktop-Version=1.0
clementine:clementine.desktop-Type=Application
clementine:clementine.desktop-Name=Clementine
```

gmusicbrowser

```
gmusicbrowser:gmusicbrowser.desktop:X-AppInstall-Popcon=498
gmusicbrowser:gmusicbrowser.desktop-X-AppInstall-Section=universe
gmusicbrowser:gmusicbrowser.desktop-
gmusicbrowser:gmusicbrowser.desktop-Name=gmusicbrowser
gmusicbrowser:gmusicbrowser.desktop-Comment=Jukebox for large collections of mp3/ogg/flac/mpc
gmusicbrowser:gmusicbrowser.desktop-Exec=gmusicbrowser %F
```

mpv

```
mpv:mpv.desktop:X-AppInstall-Popcon=126
mpv:mpv.desktop-X-AppInstall-Section=universe
mpv:mpv.desktop-
mpv:mpv.desktop-Type=Application
mpv:mpv.desktop-Name=mpv Media Player
mpv:mpv.desktop-GenericName=Multimedia player
```

vlc

```
vlc:vlc.desktop:X-AppInstall-Popcon=19735
vlc:vlc.desktop-X-AppInstall-Section=universe
vlc:vlc.desktop-
vlc:vlc.desktop-Version=1.0
vlc:vlc.desktop-Name=VLC media player
vlc:vlc.desktop-GenericName=Media player
```

Once you have this output, you can clean it up further and perhaps stick it into a spreadsheet for further study.

---

<sup>I don't know how often the Popcon scores are updated. The .desktop files on my system are dated 20150910!</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, sort of, check out [appgrid](http://www.appgrid.org/) **16.04+ Only**

```
wget ppa.launchpad.net/appgrid/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/a/appgrid/appgrid_0.278_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i appgrid_0.278_all.deb
```

It is a software centre alternative.

Why sort of? Well, it only had one sorting option "Top Rated" (may change if you sing up or use it a lot)and they only seem to use three star ratings but it is presented the way you want

[image]

As far as I know, this is the only one but visit their site and make a feature request, they may add it for you.